# Adjective of "testosterone"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Is there an adjective form for the noun *testosterone?* A word to fill the blanks in:

> All of the team’s members are muscly men. It’s a ______ team.

I’d rather not have a phrase if I can help it.

EDIT: To clarify, in this example, the team contains of all men who are strong, aggressive as usually associated with having (too much) testosterone. Or at least they think they do. Actually they're just jerks-slash-bullies. Also, they gave this name to themselves, so maybe there's a bit of boasting in there.

EDIT 2: Since it looks like my example above is somewhat misleading from my intentions covered in my first Edit, here's a revised example:

> We are all strong, muscly men. We are the _______ team.

Hopefully now it's clearer that it's a name the team gave themselves, it's a bit boastful, and most importantly, it's a single word.

Comment: My accepted answer is governed by the wisdom I gained from this meta answer http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/1158/88539

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A one-word option is [testosteronic](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/testosteronic), defined by Wiktionary as

> Relating to testosterone; characterized by aggressive masculinity.

You can see some examples of actual usage at [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/testosteronic).

This way of forming an adjective would fit with *testosterone*'s derivation, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone#History), from *testicle* + *sterol* + *ketone* (as a corresponding adjective to *ketone* is [*ketonic*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ketonic)).

Comment: Hmm, I like the fact that it uses the adjective form of one of its root words.

Comment: This is rarely heard in general speech though (I had never heard it before).

Comment: Somehow that makes it better :D

Answer (score 32):

*All of the team’s members are muscly men. It’s a **macho** team.*

Comment: This is by far the most appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, but refer to the part that they choose this team name for themselves, so there's a bit of boasting inherent in the name.

Comment: @StorymasterQ: Perhaps this works even better:  "All of the team’s members are muscly men; they're the ***Macho Men***".

Comment: @StorymasterQ Forget the other answers! "Macho" is the one.

Answer (score 12):

How about ***testosterone*** itself, i.e.:

> All of the team’s members are muscly men. It’s a testosterone team.

English compounds allows you to use every noun as an adjective, if you so wish. Therefore, there is little, if no difference between *testosterone team* and *testosterony team* (to pick an example).

Comment: Hmm, perhaps, but I'd like something grander. Something to evoke the sense of a testosterone-filled team (without being a phrase like testosterone-filled).

Comment: Technically, that is not an adjective, but an attributive noun.

Comment: @reinierpost: Hence “if you so wish”. And I am not the first to call this noun usage *adjectival* or similar ([example](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)).

Comment: Yes, others dilute terminology all the time.

Comment: @StorymasterQ *testosterone-filled* isn't technically a phrase.

Comment: @ErikE, yes, Mari-Lou had told me about compound words in the comments for [Elian's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/299275/88539)

Comment: @StorymasterQ Sorry to have repeated!

Answer (score 10):

Consider,

***testosterone-packed***

> packed: filled with a large amount of something [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/packed)

***smashmouth***

> characterized by brute force without finesse [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/smashmouth)

Comment: "I’d rather not have a phrase if I can help it."

Comment: @StorymasterQ strictly speaking it's a compound word

Answer (score 8):

You could consider using **testosterone-filled** as an adjective. Using "[-filled](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/-filled)", you could make an adjective as defined in Collins Online Dictionary:

> (in combination) filled with the specified object: '*another
>   sunshine-filled day*', '*a fun-filled day out*', '*flower-filled*' and '*smoke-filled*'.

Actual usage:

> Every team needs a secret weapon. It’s what makes a group special and
>   gives them an added oomph, that extra push that gets them over
>   whatever bumps lie in the road ahead. Even Expendables 2 needed Chuck
>   Norris to make its already **testosterone-filled team** of balding
>   gunslingers seem unique.

[[Hoopshabit.com]](http://hoopshabit.com/2014/09/18/cleveland-cavaliers-dion-waiters-x-factor/)

I am not sure if you watched the movie [The Expendable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Expendables_(2010_film)), most of the characters are muscly, sometimes jerks-slash-bullies.

Answer (score 5):

It's a [ballsy](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ballsy) team.

> balls·y  (bôl′zē)
>   adj. balls·i·er, balls·i·est Vulgar Slang Bold or
>   daring, often in a reckless or aggressive way.
>   [From balls, testicles.]

Answer (score 2):

**high-testosterone**

I'm not sure if it's a word or not, but it's similar in form to "high-octane" so will be easily understood.

Answer (score 2):

A common idiom that immediately sprang to mind for me is [**testosterone-fuelled**](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/definition/testosterone) (see the usage example for definition 2).

And here's a real example of usage (very similar to your context) in [The Tab](http://thetab.com/2015/01/02/strong-men-campus-testosterone-fuelled-life-student-powerlifter-27746).

Answer (score 1):

All of the team’s members are muscly men. It’s a **testosterone-ridden** team.

Comment: Well, that has a decidedly negative sound, to my ear.

Comment: That might actually be what the OP is asking.  But most of the other suggestions are more neutral, and I can't imagine someone describing themselves with this adjective.

Answer (score 0):

All of the team's members are muscly men. It's a machismo team.

Macho is good . . . but machismo is better. It has the negative connotations that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

How about simply using:
**Manly**

or something with a slightly more negative  connotation: 
**Manly Man/Men**

Answer (score -1):

Possibly insufficiently er... macho, but trying to cleave more closely to the OP -

We are all strong, muscly men. We are the ***Testosteronee*** team.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a slang term that meatheads would use for their own name: Diesel

We are all strong, muscly men. We are the **diesel** team.

We are all strong, muscly men. We are **Team Diesel**.